# Passing an argument to a SynthDef doesn't register when synth is initialized

Tags: supercollider

I have a simple SynthDef where I want to use the `CCIn` class, like so:

```
(
SynthDef(\lfo_sin, {|bus, amp, myArg|
    var m = CCIn.new;
    var v = [300, 700, \exp].asSpec;
    var sig = SinOsc.ar(m.kr(0, myArg, v), mul:amp);
    Out.ar(bus, sig);
}).add;
)
```

When I instantiate it like so `y = Synth(\lfo_sin, [\bus, 0, \amp, 1, \myArg, 71]);`, to match with the MIDI CC on my MIDI controller, I am not able to use the `CCIn.kr` method like I should.

If I however directly type in the MIDI CC when I define the SynthDef like so:

```
(
SynthDef(\lfo_sin2, {|bus, amp|
    var m = CCIn.new;
    var v = [300, 700, \exp].asSpec;
    var sig = SinOsc.ar(m.kr(0, 71, v), mul:amp);
    Out.ar(bus, sig);
}).add;
)
```

everything runs like it should and I am able to control the frequency using my MIDI controller.

Why does this behavior happen and how can I modify my code so that I can pass in the MIDI CC when initializing the synth or *setting* the argument afterwards?

Answer (score 0):

If you take a look at the source for CCIn, you can see it's doing something a bit more complex than an ordinary UGen:

```
    kr { |chan = 0, num = 0, spec = \amp, lag = 0.05|
        var outArray = [chan, num, spec, lag].flop.collect{ |args| 
            var ch, n, sp, lg;
            # ch, n, sp, lg = args;
            (sp.asSpec.map( In.kr(this.prGetBus(ch, n).index) ).lag3(lg))
            };
        if (outArray.size>1) {^outArray} {^(outArray[0])} //fix to work with muliout
```

Specifically, this...

*`this.prGetBus(ch, n)`*

is using the provided channel and number (`ch` and `n`) to look up the `Bus` from which it can read the MIDI data (see `prGetBus`). It's doing this lookup as part of BUILDING the SynthDef, not RUNNING the Synth, so once it's been built the bus it's reading from is pretty much fixed. The CCIn quark obscures some fairly complex things under the hood in order to behave as a simple UGen, so it's unlikely you'll easily be able to get the behavior you're looking for.

Here are a few alternatives.

**1. Write your MIDI data to a bus yourself**

```
// One for each cc number
~ccBusses = 127.collect({
    Bus.control(s, 1);
}); 

// A midi responder that sets the value of the right bus
MIDIdef.cc(\cc, {
    |value, cc|
    ~ccBusses[cc].set(value);
}, ccNum: (0..127) )   // meaning: all cc values

// Once those are set up, to map a cc to a new synth use:
Synth(\mySynth, args:[\freq, ~ccBusses[10].asMap]);
```

**2. Using the Connection quark**

```
// Create a value between 100..2400, controlled by MIDI
~freq = MIDIControlValue(spec:ControlSpec(100, 2400));
~freq.cc_(10); // cc number 10

// Run your synth
~note = Synth(\mySynth, args:[\freq, ~freq]);

// Connect the value of ~freq to the \freq argument of your synth. Now, MIDI changes will be broadcast to your synth.
~freq.signal(\value).connectTo(~note.argSlot(\freq));
```